# Java Swing JMenuItem intercepts its accelerator key even entered into a JTextField component

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jmenuitem, jmenubar

Example code:

```
public class FrameMenuTextFieldTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField());
                JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item1");
                item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Menu Item clicked");
                    }
                });
                item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_5, 0));
                menu.add(item);
                menubar.add(menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The problem here is if I type `5` into the textfield, not only the textfield gets this event, but the menu item as well, and its action is performed; message shown.

What is the simplest way to disable the key event propagation to the menu bar?

I my real application, I have a lot of menu items to disable for a few textfields.

Comment: I think its not possible without using any modifier. Can you specify in your post that you **don't want to use any modifier**. So that you can get the corrected answer.

Comment: Even if you specify a modifier, e.g. **SHIFT+5**, and type **SHIFT+5** inside the textfield, the menu item's action will be preformed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the `JMenuItem` with some modifiers such as Ctrl, Alt, Shift etc. *if possible* as mentioned here [KeyStroke#getKeyStroke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29).

Try something like as shown below to bind it with `Ctrl+5`.

```
item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_5, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
```

---

#### EDIT

It might help you if you don't want to use any modifier.

If the current focusable component is not `JTextField` then perform action on `JMenuItem`.

Sample code:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item1");
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component component = frame.getFocusOwner();
        if (!(component instanceof JTextField)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Menu Item clicked");
        }
    }
});
```

Read more here on [In Swing, how can I find out what object currently has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720208/in-swing-how-can-i-find-out-what-object-currently-has-focus)

Comment: It there any serious issue with post. Please leave comments so that I can learn it.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a solution: I don't want CTRL, I want only the 5 as an accelerator. Also if I press CTRL+5 inside the textfield, the message is also shown.

Comment: OK let me try if possible.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! I am still waiting for a little bit maybe to have a global solution for all the menu items in a menu or menu bar, because I have a lot of items and doing this one by one would be awful.

Comment: Awesome!  your fix worked for me after I had been banging my head against the wall for the past hour!