# How do I find out whether my object (not a component) is in focus or not?

Tags: java, swing, focus

How do I find out whether my object (image) is in focus or not in Java?

[How to find out which object currently has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720208/in-swing-how-can-i-find-out-what-object-currently-has-focus)

In this link I get focus about component but I want focusing on image.

Comment: Only components can have focus...

Comment: ok, it means we cant focus on image inside viewport?? plaese help

Comment: How are the images displayed in this viewport?  How do you distinguish between all the other images that might be in this viewport? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You can always add in image to a JLabel as an Icon and then add the label to the panel. Or you can use a JList and add an Icon to the JList. The JList contains a selection listener which you can use to know which item in the list is currently selected.